# Center text inside Text component, React Native

Tags: react-native

I have Text component slightly higher than the actual text inside it. Is it possible to align center this text inside its background vertically?

Text is here:

```
<Text style={styles.container}>{this.props.title}</Text>
```

Styles are here:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        height: 30,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
    }
});
```

Comment: Set the `lineHeight` of the text same as the `Text` components height

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting `lineHeight` of the component same as the `height` should fix it.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        height: 30,
        lineHeight: 30,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I encounterd this problem, lineHeight faied to center text on Android.
see:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13126

then Text style property "textAlignVertical" could be the solution, see
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text-style-props.html#textalignvertical

An example:

```
<Text style={{textAlignVertical: 'center', textAlign:'center'}}>Horizontal and Vertical centerd text</Text>
```

Comment: On IOS, you should use lineHeight. So It's better to have both of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        fontWeight: 'bold';
        background: grey;
        width: 40%;
        border: 1px solid black;
        margin: auto;
        text-align: center;   
        position: center;
        padding: 16px;
    }
});
```